# Why does a function call with jQuery components reload the xhtml page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, bootsfaces

I am working with JSF, Primefaces and Bootsfaces. I am developing a navbar and I must create a  dropmenu in navbar, however I had a problem with `b:dropmenu` implementation and I used another solution.

My problem is when I on click in `Nombre de usuario` the page reloads if I call `mostrarOpcionesUsuario()`, but if I replace `mostrarOpcionesUsuario();` to `alert('hello!');`, the system shows `alert` and doesn't refresh the page. I need to call `mostrarOpcionesUsuario()` without refreshing the page.

This is my code:

XHTML:

```
<b:navbar>
    <b:navbarLinks>
        <b:navLink onmousedown= "mostrarOpcionesUsuario(); return false;">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            Nombre de usuario
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class = "ulOpciones">
                        <li>Web Design</li>
                        <li>Web Development</li>
                        <li>Illustrations</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </b:navLink>
    </b:navbarLinks>
</b:navBar>
```

JavaScript:

```
function mostrarOpcionesUsuario() {
    $(".ulOpciones").css('visibility', function (i, v) {
        if (v == 'hidden') {
            $(".ulOpciones").css({'visibility': 'visible'});
        } else {
            $(".ulOpciones").css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
        }
    });
}
```

Is the same case if I put `alert` in `mostrarOpcionesUsuario()`, the page doesn't reload, but with the previous `mostrarOpcionesUsuario` implementation, the page reloads.

Help me, please!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
<b:navLink href="javascript:mostrarOpcionesUsuario()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've answered your question yourself: the BootsFaces `<b:navLink>`has several different options to define what happens when it's clicked. One of them is the `href` attribute, and this attribute in turn allows you to call JavaScript by simply preceding `javascript:`.

Another, possibly more intuitive solution is to use the `onclick` handler instead of the `onmousedown` handler. This does the trick, too:

```
<b:navLink onclick="mostrarOpcionesUsuario(); return false;">
```

Comment: I had the same problem with onlick

Comment: That's strange. I tested the approach before posting the answer. The difference between `onmousedown` and `onclick` is that `onmousedown` is only a part of the act of clicking. Hence JavaScript applications tend to ignore `onmousedown` in favor of `onclick`.